# Control location manager update interval

Tags: location, cllocationmanager

Is there a way to control the update interval of the location manager? I used the nearest 10 meter setting for accuracy but it appears that my application gets one update every second, which I think is too often. I want the good accuracy but not the frequency.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Location Manager update frequency, iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385102/location-manager-update-frequency-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

I did it with a timer:

in the header add:

```
ServerInterface *serverInterface;
```

in the .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
...
[frequentLocationUpdateTimer invalidate];
frequentLocationUpdateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30 target:self selector:
               @selector(reEnableLocationTick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
...
}
- (void)reEnableLocationTick:(NSTimer *)theTimer
{
    [locationGetter startUpdates]; //Maybe you have to change this line according to your code
}
```

and in your locationmanager...:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manage didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    ...

        if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 100)
    {
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];  
    } 
    ...

    // let our delegate know we're done
    [delegate newPhysicalLocation:newLocation];
}
```

The code simply stops updating the location after reaching a minimum accuracy of 100m. Then, every 30sec a timer reenables the locationmanager again.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding to my question. Are you sure stopping the update is the right solution? I found out that when initially starting the updating, it took 5-10 updates to get the accurate location. If the update is stopped ans restarted, it may also require calibration time. This may not be acceptable to the application. Anyone has comments? Thanks...

Comment: Hi, sry i forgot to tell you something. In my case -stopUpdatingLocation only suppresses the call of the delegate ;).

Comment: Thanks again. Why you say that "in your case" it suppresses the call of the delegate? Is it true that [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation] call will  suppresses the location update? Now, most importantly, do you know that when [locationManager startUpdatingLocation} is called again, the location updated is called right away and no calibration time is necessary?