# Location Manager update frequency, iphone

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

I have a CLLocation manager called "myLocation".

```
myLocation = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    myLocation.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation ;
    myLocation.distanceFilter = 10 ;
    myLocation.delegate=self;



    locationEnabledBool = [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];



    if (locationEnabledBool ==NO || ( [CLLocationManager  authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)) {

    //  LocationText.text = @"Location Service Disabled ";
        UIAlertView *locationAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location Service Disabled" 
                                                        message:@"To re-enable, please go to Settings and turn on Location Service for this app." 
                                                       delegate:nil 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [locationAlert show];
        [locationAlert release];

    }

        [myLocation startUpdatingLocation];
```

and location update function is

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

NSLog(@"old location is %f, %f ", oldLocation.coordinate.latitude, oldLocation.coordinate.longitude);
NSLog(@"new location is %f,%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude );
}
```

Is there a way to find frequency of location manager update, and If it can be increased or decreased?

Comment: There is no such option in location manager....The delegate will be called whenever a change in location is detected. But u can vary the accuracy...That is whether it should be changed for every ten metres change or 100 m  or 1 Km..etc...

Comment: But Location update also takes place if device is stationary.

Comment: you mean u can get the coordinates of the location even when the device is stationary.... ?

Comment: Yes. Coordinates of current location change does change when location update takes place and device is stationary. this change is is small (only 5th onwards decimal places changes)

Comment: how often it keeps changing ? can u show some of ur code pls ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your location update starts only when you call the method `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation]`.

You can control the frequency of the update using an `NSTimer`. Call the `startUpdatingLocation` method at regular intervals whenever you need a location update and then immediately call the `stopUpdatingLocation` method. The next time you will get a location update only at the interval you have set in the `NSTimer`.

Comment: Thanks for your patience for helping me out. your answer certainly helped. next time I will be ask question more clearly.

Comment: @amol-subhedar i need a favour from u... could u pls help me out ? :)

Comment: certainly.. what favour do you need?

Comment: my scenario is like this....I need gps coordinates to change continuosly.....even when am stationary...it should detect sligtest movement changes inside a room..how u were able to achieve tat...i tried ur code..but it s not changing for me....hope u can get me.....just exact opposite of wat u asked..... :)

Comment: you are right. If you are moving anywhere coordinates will not change "continuously". In my opinion location update takes place at fixed interval of time. each time it will try to determine location coordinates . But since it can never determine exact coordinates It will treat previous stored value as initial guess value and determine new coordinates even if device is stationary. So we get new coordinates within given error bound. I hope this help. Bur I am not sure of this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3367/discussion-between-amol-subhedar-and-booleanboy)

Comment: booleanBoy - use the acclerometer to discover slight changes such as that

Comment: I don't think NSTimer (or Timer in Swift) will help in background mode.  My experience is it won't fire when app is in background mode.

Comment: so the question is how often iphone uses gps module to get a new location, what is default time interval?

Answer (score 6):

For detecting even the slightest of movements, you need to set

```
myLocation.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone ;
```

But, please keep in mind,letting location manager to generate updates for even the slightest of movements can end up in lot of battery usage.

Comment: distanceFilter is in meters value, you can keep myLocation.distanceFilter = 1000;