# location manager - only getting 1 update per second

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I'm timing speed runs in cars. I'm using the usual location manager code.

viewDidLoad

```
CLLocationManager   *locMgr;
if (locMgr == nil)
    locMgr = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locMgr setDelegate:self];
[locMgr requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
[locMgr setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
[locMgr setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation];
[locMgr startUpdatingLocation];
```

DELEGATE

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *) manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *) locations 
{
(process update)
}
```

QUESTION

Even though I'm using the most precise DistanceFilter and Desired Accuracy, I'm only getting one update per second while the car is moving, even at 60 mph.   I checked the number of locations returned to the delegate every second and it's always one.  Can anyone explain this?  It seems to me that I should be getting a constant stream of updates at 60 mph.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please see this [answer on how to use NSTimer to control update frequency](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7385397/1117968).

Comment: Thank you. I (1) kicked off a timer in viewDidLoad, (2) the timer ran 10 times per second and only did a startUpdatingLocation and (3) didUpdateLocations did a stopUpdatingLocation at the end. Since  didUpdateLocations ran 10 times per second instead of once, I thought I had a solution, but it seems like I'm only getting a new location and speed once per second. I think the answer lies in figuring out how to get didUpdateLocations to return results more often than once per second when I'm moving fast WITHOUT timers. At 60 mph, I'm traveling ~90 ft/sec.  I yield to the experts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to iOS development as I'm just starting to port my speedometer app from Android, and this question came up in my search for locations update rate. Hopefully it's ok that I can't answer the question but merely add info I've learned from Android.

So, iOS is probably different but Android sends out location updates whenever the (for example) GPS service gets a new location, and from experience 99.99% of Android phones and tablets have sensors that send updates once per second. If sensors of the same quality and energy efficiency are used by Apple (idk) then I'd expect 1Hz updates are the best we'll get.

My Android app can use Bluetooth GPS receivers at ~10Hz so I want my app to report the latest location whenever it's received, so timers won't really work for me.

Your question has helped me as I now know when location is updated.