# Can I adjust the frequency of locationManager (_: didUpdateLocations :)?

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

In the simulator, this method is executed only once.

However, when tested with a real mobile phone, it runs as many times as it is at the same location.

I want to control the frequency of this method.

Or is it possible through the distanceFilter?

What should I do if possible?

I suspect that the locationManager (_: didUpdateLocations :) method is automatically run whenever the location changes, so I can not control it.

Is there a way?

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class MainViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        // my source code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't use** the function `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateTo newLocation: CLLocation, from oldLocation: CLLocation)` it has been deprecated since iOS 6.

[deprecated method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423716-locationmanager)

Setting the desired accuracy should fix the problem of getting many updates with relatively the same point. For tracking with a little less precision maybe try

`locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters`

If you are concerned with long running tracking tasks/jobs then consider implementing

`func locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates(CLLocationManager)`

`func locationManagerDidResumeLocationUpdates(CLLocationManager)`

They will inform you the the location is not changing and to save power the device will shut down some hardware.

[CLLocationMangager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager)

[CLLocationManagerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate)

Answer (score 0):

You can set location accuracy like

```
self. locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
```

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationaccuracy

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you can control It. You can use `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateTo newLocation: CLLocation, from oldLocation: CLLocation) { }` method. This method gives you last location and new location and on the behalf of these locations, you can perform your desired function.

Or you can refer this answer [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385102/location-manager-update-frequency-iphone?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score -1):

Locations don’t change with the simulator. You’ll only get a single call from the didupdatelocations callback. Running on a real device will cause the completion handler to continuously fire. You can simulate a location with a GPX file but I don’t believe it fires more that once using the simulator.

Desired accuracy does change the frequency of firing but the frequency also depends on the GPS hardware and battery life status. iOS control the frequency to a certain point to optimize device performance and longevity