# How to track user location across all view controllers in an ios app?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, geofire

I am building an app that tracks a users location while the app is open and query it with geofire. I would like to keep the location updating from any view controller the user may have open. I am wondering how to do this.

Currently, I have my geofire and location tracking set up in my main view controller. In order to have the location tracking working across all view controllers, do I have to code each individual view controller to track the location, or can I place the code into, for example, the app delegate file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place the code in AppDelegate. Maybe use a timer while hitting the server so that the performance is optimized

Refer this answer:
[Location Manager update frequency, iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385102/location-manager-update-frequency-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

Put it in app delegate.swift

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()


self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization() 

// For use in foreground
self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

//Here Get Late long.
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this code will hleps but you have to use this in your all viewcontrollers

```
var LocationManager = CLLocationManager()
LocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

if( CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse ||
    CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() ==  .authorizedAlways){

  print("currentLocation = \(LocationManager.location)")

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [HSLocationManager](https://github.com/IMHitesh/HSLocationManager) for infinite location tracking in the active and inactive state.

> Location manager that allows getting background location updates every
>   n seconds with desired location accuracy.
>
> **Advantage:**
>
> - OS will never kill our app if the location manager is currently
>     running.
> - Give periodically location update when it required(range is between 2 - 
>     170 seconds (limited by max allowed background task time))
> - Customizable location accuracy and time period.
> - Low memory consumption(Singleton class)
> - Less battery draining.